# Find the center of the ellipsoid

Tags: matlab, math, least-squares

I want to use the following Matlab script to fit an ellipsoid:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24693-ellipsoid-fit

But I want also understand the math. I am stuck here:

```
% find the center of the ellipsoid
center = -A( 1:3, 1:3 ) \ v( 7:9 );
```

Where 'A' is the algebraic form of the ellipsoid. So my question is: What is the relation between the 'algebraic ellipsoid form' and the 'ellipsoid center'.

Comment: I think this is more a math problem then a programming problem.

Comment: Yes your are right.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, but algebraic ellipsoid form probably refers to the form of the equation (Cartesian or spherical coordinates, etc.) whereas ellipsoid center probably refers to the center, on the RHS of the equation for an ellipsoid.  This link may help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html

Comment: You might be interested in the corresponding 2D problem, [Compute center, axes and rotation from equation of ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1217796/35416) or [Standard form of ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18023043/1468366). My answers there do translation before center, though, so it'd not 1:1 the same as the Matlab code you're looking at. Nevertheless, you might be able to get a broader understanding of the whole subject from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the ellipsoid is given in homogeneous coordinates as

```
            ⎡v1 v4 v5 v7 ⎤   ⎡x⎤
            ⎢v4 v2 v6 v8 ⎥   ⎢y⎥
[x y z 1] * ⎢v5 v6 v3 v9 ⎥ * ⎢z⎥ = 0
            ⎣v7 v8 v9 v10⎦   ⎣1⎦
```

which you can also write without homogeneous coordinates as

```
          ⎡v1 v4 v5⎤   ⎡x⎤                 ⎡v7⎤
[x y z] * ⎢v4 v2 v6⎥ * ⎢y⎥ + 2 * [x y z] * ⎢v8⎥ + v10 = 0
          ⎣v5 v6 v3⎦   ⎣z⎦                 ⎣v9⎦
```

If the second summand is zero, this describes an ellipsoid centered in the origin, since for every point [x,y,z] its mirror image [-x,-y,-z] will lead to the same result. So the second (i.e. linear) term is what shifts the ellipsoid out from the center.

If you start with an ellipsoid centered at the origin and then shift the center to [cx,cy,cz] you'd end up with something of the form

```
                   ⎡v1 v4 v5⎤   ⎡x-cx⎤
[x-cx y-cy z-cz] * ⎢v4 v2 v6⎥ * ⎢y-cy⎥ = const.
                   ⎣v5 v6 v3⎦   ⎣z-cz⎦
```

or in vector notation (writing `A` for the 3×3 matrix in question)

```
(x-c) * A * (x-c) = x*A*x - 2*x*A*c + c*A*c = const.
```

I know in Matlab you'd need some `'` in there somewhere to transpose some of the vectors, but you get the idea. Comparing the above to what I wrote further up, you can see that essentially you want the linear terms to be equal, i.e.

```
-2*x*A*c = 2*x*v(7:9)
    -A*c = v(7:9)

  ⎡v1 v4 v5⎤   ⎡cx⎤   ⎡v7⎤
- ⎢v4 v2 v6⎥ * ⎢cy⎥ = ⎢v8⎥
  ⎣v5 v6 v3⎦   ⎣cz⎦   ⎣v9⎦
```

which means you have a linear system of equations here which you can solve for `c`, using the code you quoted. It takes the upper left 3×3 matrix from the homogeneous description, and it takes the three elements from `v` corresponding to the linear term (which I assume could have been written as `A(4, 1:3)` but I'm no Matlab expert) then it uses `\` to solve the linear system of equations. Not sure whether operator precedence is such that the `-` gets applied to the matrix `A` or to the solution, but as the result is the same either way, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thx for the useful answer. I think I can follow parts of your explanation. I understood formula 1.) and 2.). Formula 3.) is an ellipsoid shifted out of the center. But formula 1.) is also an ellipsoid shifted out of the center. What is the difference ?

Comment: @Mark: 1.) and 2.) are equivalent, merely different notation. 3.) uses different variables and a different arrangement of them, in order to make the coordinates of the center more readily apparent. By making 2.) and 3.) equal one another, you can take the form from 1.) or 2.) and extract the center as seen in 3.). So once you solve the equation to compute c, 2.) and 3.) are equal, too.

Comment: Okay. So there are some additional steps required to form 3.) from 1.) or 2.). I tried it but without success. Then I expand 4.) to x*A*x - 2*x*A*c + c*A*c.But now I do not understand the step from 4.) to 5.)

Comment: @Mark: Addendum to your first question: the relationship between 2.) and 3.) is like a circle described either as `x²+y²+ax+by+c=0` (similar to 2.) or as `(x-cx)²+(y-cy)²=r²` (similar to 3.). You can compute cx,cy,r from a,b,c. This is the kind of conversioin we are doing here for ellipsoids, in subsequent steps. Now for 5.), see how 2.) has the form `x*A*x + 2*x*v(7:9) + v10 = 0`. So the quadratic term from 2.) and 4.) is the same, the constant terms can always be recombined so 4.) doesn't care too much. Thus comparing the linear terms from 4.) and 2.) is what leads to 5.). Does this help?

Comment: We come closer. I am still stuck at 5.). Does it mean I have to set 2.) = 4.) so the quadratic terms are canceled ?

Comment: @Mark: Essentially yes. I'd say “equal” not “canceled”. And strictly speaking, both of them already are equations. So you'd do a comparison of coefficients, with one equation for each power, but concentrating on power 1 (linear) since that's the one relevant for the center.

Comment: Can you provide any reference for equations 1 and 2? Surprisingly difficult to find a clear reference for. In particular, I don't understand the origin of the factor of 2 in the second summand in equation 2.

Comment: @ColinBroderick https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric has something similar but being for arbitrary dimension it's harder to read, and they also put the ones in coordinate index zero not in the end. Personally I derived this from the 2d case following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections. The factor 2 comes from the use of a symmetric matrix, where e.g. for the x term you get x*v7*1+1*v7*x using the matrix entries 1,4 and 4,1 which are both v7. Some prefer to omit the factor 2 there and write v7/2 in the matrix instead. Both work as long as you stick to it.

Comment: Thanks @MvG. I suspected it was somewhat arbitrary since other treatments I've read have the factor of 1/2 elsewhere as you stated.